# s3 bucket policy to access object url

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-policies, aws-permissions

What is s3 bucket policy permission to provide an IAM user to access object url which is basically an HTTPs url for the object that i have uploaded to S3 bucket.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "ListBucket",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "GetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

With above policy i can download the object into my local , but i cant access it with object url which includes Https link. If i keep the s3 bucket full public , only then i can have the https access to the object url.

I dont want to provide full public access and how to provide access to this with bucket policy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get https url by generating [s3 pre-signed urls](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html) for the objects. This will allow for **temporary** access using the urls generated.

Other than that, a common choice is to share your s3 objects with an outside world **without making your bucket public** using CloudFront as explained in:

- [Amazon S3 + Amazon CloudFront: A Match Made in the Cloud](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/amazon-s3-amazon-cloudfront-a-match-made-in-the-cloud/)

Answer (score 0):

Objects in Amazon S3 are private by default. They are not accessible via an anonymous URL.

If you want a specific IAM User to be able to access the bucket, then you can add permissions to the IAM User themselves. Then, when accessing the bucket, they will need to identify themselves and prove their identity. This is best done by **making API calls to Amazon S3**, which include authentication.

If you must access the private object via a URL, then you can create an [Amazon S3 pre-signed URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html), which is a time-limited URL that provides temporary access to a private object. This proves your ownership and will let S3 serve the content to you. A pre-signed URL can be generated with a couple of lines of code.